# matlab interface to berkeley db

Tags: database, matlab, nosql, berkeley-db

how can one use berkeley db from Matlab? or is there a good way for matlab to access/store huge key/value data? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Oracle Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Matlab Database Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/database/) for various database problems (connecting, sending, etc.).

Comment: It seems that berkeley DB does not have JDBC/ODBC layer to be used in Matlab Database toolbox?